# How to show a structure (list of classes/methods/functions) of a source file on GitHub?

Tags: github

While browsing the source code of many projects on GitHub, I often want to quickly get to know the structure of a long C++/Python/JS/Go/Rust source file e.g. [ImHex' window.cpp](https://github.com/WerWolv/ImHex/blob/master/main/source/window/window.cpp), without cloning the repo or downloading the source file and opening it in my code editor. For example, Notepad++ shows a list of functions in this file:

[image: Notepad++ Functions List]

But is there a bookmarklet/extension/user script to show it on GitHub website, as a sidebar next to the source code? Otherwise, which libraries can I use to create it?

Answer (score 0):

By pressing [the dot key while viewing a source file](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2021/08/31/github-vs-code.aspx) on GitHub, VS Code Online will be opened, which has the outline pane:

[image: VS Code Online outline]

That said, there are also JS/CS libraries which show an outline/structure view:

- [Symbols Tree View](https://github.com/xndcn/symbols-tree-view)
- [Structure View](https://github.com/alibaba/structure-view)
- [Brackets Outline List](https://github.com/Hirse/brackets-outline-list)